# Set orientation programmatically but also listen for orientation changes?

Tags: android, rotation, landscape-portrait, onconfigurationchanged

Is it possible to set the orientation for an activity but to also listen for orientation changes using onConfigurationChanged()? In my activity, I want to start another activity when the user rotates the phone to landscape position, and to come back to that activity when the phone is rotated back to portrait. The only way I can listen for that is if I don't explicitly set to portrait or landscape using setRequestedOrientation() or android:orientation in the manifest.

If there is no way to set the orientation but also listens for rotation changes, how can I manually prevent the os from rotating my views on a configuration change?

Comment: In the manifest for the activity I use `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to keep the orientation in portrait mode. I don't know if onConfigurationChanged still gets called when the device is rotated but if it does maybe you can use it to launch a new activity (or for the 2nd activity sense if need to finish() that activity).

Comment: onConfigurationChanged will not get called if you do that

Comment: In looking at the documentation for Handling Runtime Changes it looks like if you use `android:configChanges:orientation|screenSize` and handle the `onConfigurationChanged()` yourself you can selectively determine what you want to do. I am just getting this by reading and haven't actually used this, but it seems that if you implement onConfigurationChanged() the OS assumes you do everything. You are probably already aware of this but here is the url where I read about it.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html Hope that helps.

Comment: I did try this. I started another activity on orientation changes, so I had one activity for landscape and one for portrait. The only issue was when I clicked back, it would take me to the "portrait" activity, but it would be in the landscape mode so it would show the view tilted for landscape which isn't what I wanted, that view always has to be in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up scraping this idea and instead working with the android framework and having a landscape and portrait layout file. I don't think what I was trying to do is even possible.